# MS ACCESS: How to make an update query with group by clause

Tags: ms-access, group-by, sql-update

First, sorry for any inaccuracy in notions, as my native language is not English and I have an access to ACCESS :) only from my university (and now I'm home).

I need a help concerning MS ACCESS program.
In my minimal example have two tables:

1. `user` with three columns: `id`, `nick` and `disabled` (true/false type)
2. `warnings` with two columns: `user_id` and `date`

There's also a relation between these two columns, by the pair `id` <--> `user_id`.
I would like to disable all users that have 3 or more warnings.

I can easily make a select query that finds all such users, by using GROUP BY clause:

```
user.id / group by
warnings.user_id / count / criterion: >=3 / not visible
```

When I try to change it into update query, the GROUP BY clause disappear. I tried to tackle this problem by saving the select query above as QUERY1 and create another update query that uses QUERY1.
I would need something like:
**update all rows from user such that id is inside QUERY1**.
I tried putting such statement in two places:

a) as a criterion in `user`.id row:

```
  user.id / criterion: user.id belongs to QUERY1.
  user.disabled / set true
```

b) as an additional row:
b1)

```
user.id
user.disabled / set true
expression1: id belongs to QUERY1 / criterion: true
```

or
b2)

```
user.id
user.disabled / set true
expression1: look for id in QUERY1 / criterion: not null
```

Looking for help on the internet I found some information about **subqueries**, but unfortunately my attempts failed. I also found a function **DLookup** (I think fruitful for b2 approach). I think I don't understand the use of square brackets in ACCESS syntax.

What is important for me, the solution should be as easy and 'clickable' as possible, as I need to explain it to some group of people that are totally beginners.

I thank you for any help I'll obtain from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment above, 'group by' makes no sense directly in an update query.  What you need to do is use the results of a grouped query inside an update query.  That either means a separate grouped query which is referenced by your update query, or it means a grouped subquery inside your update.  I'll show the latter as it is more direct.  I'm not totally sure what 'clickable' means to you, but the 2 query approach should be easy enough to work out from the example with a subquery, if you prefer that instead.  (subquery is more contained and terse, but introduces the concept of subqueries which might be a complication)

```
update user 
set disabled = true
where id in
(select user_id from warnings group by user_id having count(*) > 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I put your code in sql view in Access and then I checked how the program shows it in project mode. Then I figured out  quite easy way to explain it to my students:
First: make a select query.
Second: Make a new query with `user`.`disabled` column (set:true) and `user`.`id` column.
Third: copy the sql code from the first query. Put it inside criterion clause in `user`.`id` column in the second query inside  in(...) function.
Now it is easy enough. Thank you once more.